# Varnish or Squid as cache server with IIS

Tags: iis, squid, varnish

Can we setup a Varnish or Squid server as web cache server for IIS server?

I did not find much information anywhere. Please let me know where can I get information

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! You probably found the [varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) and [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) web sites and googled for some tutorials as a starting point. The question is; what do you want to cache? How is your website (not) cachable? Are you comfortable with linux (varnish only works on unix/linux/posix systems)? Why not stick with some Microsoft cache solution if you run IIS?